# Making a cursor for graphics using a Locator in LocatorPane

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic, locator

I am trying to add some cursors to a plot. I am using LocatorPane and form the cursors by setting the Appearance option. However, I can't seem to find out how big the cursors will be and I need them to rescale according to the data I am using.

Here is a minimum working example. First some data.

```
 data1 = Table[{f, 1/Sqrt[(100^2 - f^2)^2 + 0.1 f^2]}, {f, 0, 300, 
        0.1}];
 data2 = Table[{f, (Sqrt[0.1] 100)/
        Sqrt[(100^2 - f^2)^2 + 0.1 f^2]}, {f, 0, 300, 0.1}];
```

Here is a dynamic module which plots the data and provides the cursors.

```
ClearAll[curPlot];
curPlot[] := DynamicModule[{pt1 = {10, 0.02}, pt2 = {200, 0.02}},
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[{pt1, 
     pt2}, (pt1 = {#[[1, 1]], 0.02}; pt2 = {#[[2, 1]], 0.02}) &],
   Dynamic@
    ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
     Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 6 72],
   Appearance -> 
    Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, 3 72 /GoldenRatio}]
   ]
  ]
```

If I set

```
data = data1;
```

and then

```
curPlot[]
```

I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I now change to the other data by setting

```
data = data2;
```

The plot changes to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want the plot to change dynamically like this when data is changed.

How do I make the cursor length occupy the whole height of the plot? I have been trying to see if it is involved with the ImageSize but can't work it out at the moment.

I actually need a more advanced version with a log plot. The code is now

```
ClearAll[curPlot2];
curPlot2[] := DynamicModule[{pt1 = {10, 0.02}, pt2 = {200, 0.02}},
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[{pt1, 
     pt2}, (pt1 = {#[[1, 1]], 0.02}; pt2 = {#[[2, 1]], 0.02}) &],
   Dynamic@
    ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
     ImageSize -> 6 72, Frame -> True],
   Appearance -> 
    Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, 3 72/GoldenRatio }]
   ]
  ]
```

With  `data = data1;` I get nothing but with `data = data2;` I get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I really need to understand how the locator is formed and positioned. Thanks for any help.

Comment: to be clear, you want the red lines to go from the lower end to the upper end of the plot?

Comment: Exactly. Vertical lines from the bottom of the plot to the top. I have just thought that this may be difficult due to image padding.  The lines may cross the axes into the labeled tick marks. I am not going to be too fussy if that happens. The first thing is to get them onto the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT: Preserving the interface with `LocatorPane`

The problem with this is to manage to have the `Graphics` object given to the `Appearance` argument exactly of the same shape as the image generated by the `ListPlot`.
This includes, at least, same `ImageSize` and same `AspectRatio`.

I still didn't manage to have the lines exactly span the whole image, so if someone can pitch in and suggest what other graphics options I overlooked that would be great.

```
getYRangeFromPlot[plot_] := 
  AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange][[1, 2, 2]];
getAspectRatioFromPlot[plot_] := Options[plot, AspectRatio][[1, 2]];

ClearAll[curPlot];
curPlot[] := DynamicModule[{pt1 = {10, 0}, pt2 = {200, 0.}, plot},
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[{pt1, pt2},
    (pt1 = {#[[1, 1]], Mean@getYRangeFromPlot@plot}; 
      pt2 = {#[[2, 1]], Mean@getYRangeFromPlot@plot}) &
    ],
   Dynamic[
    plot = ListPlot[data,
      Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
      Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> None,
      ImageMargins -> 0
      ];
    pt1[[2]] = pt2[[2]] = Mean@getYRangeFromPlot@plot;
    plot
    ],
   Appearance -> Graphics[
     {Red, Line@{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}},
     ImageSize -> Dynamic@CurrentValue[plot, ImageSize],
     PlotRange -> All,
     AspectRatio -> Dynamic@getAspectRatioFromPlot@plot,
     PlotRangePadding -> None
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

### Reimplementing the feature with `EventHandler`

All right, this is much more involved than I wanted it to be, but at the end I found it easier to just reimplement the functionality using `EventHandler` primitives:

```
data1 = Table[{f, 1/Sqrt[(100^2 - f^2)^2 + 0.1 f^2]}, {f, 0, 300, 
    0.1}];
data2 = Table[{f, (Sqrt[0.1] 100)/
     Sqrt[(100^2 - f^2)^2 + 0.1 f^2]}, {f, 0, 300, 0.1}];

closerPoint[xCoordinates_List] := MapIndexed[
      {First@#2, Abs[MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]] - #1]} &,
      xCoordinates
      ] // SortBy[#[[2]] &] // First // First;

ClearAll@curPlot;
curPlot[] := DynamicModule[
  {
   x1, x2, xToMove,
   plotRange, plot
   },
  plotRange[] := AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange][[1, 2, 2]];
  x1 = 10;
  x2 = 200;
  EventHandler[
   Function[graphics, Dynamic[graphics, TrackedSymbols :> {data}], 
     HoldAll]@Show[
     plot = ListPlot[data,
       Joined -> True,
       PlotRange -> All,
       Frame -> True,
       Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Medium,
       PlotRangePadding -> None
       ],
     Graphics[{Red,
       Line@{{Dynamic@x1, First@plotRange[]}, {Dynamic@x1, 
          Last@plotRange[]}},
       Line@{{Dynamic@x2, First@plotRange[]}, {Dynamic@x2, 
          Last@plotRange[]}}
       }]
     ],
   {
    "MouseDown" :> 
     Set[xToMove, {Hold@x1, Hold@x2}[[closerPoint@{x1, x2}]]],
    "MouseDragged" :> (xToMove /. 
       Hold[s_] :> Set[s, MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]]])
    }
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

You can adjust the not perfect filling of the red lines by simply setting `PlotRangePadding -> None`.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. This is a whole different approach. I will look to see if I can work this in my full problem as opposed to my minimum  working example.